# Create Azure Data factory linked service or integration runtime directly in git mode wit rest api

Tags: azure-data-factory, linked-service

I am trying to create linkedservices with restapi in gitmode but the linked service is still created in live mode. My API code was

PUT [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/linkedservices/{linkedServiceName}?api-version=2018-06-01&versionType=branch&version=test_branch](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/linkedservices/%7BlinkedServiceName%7D?api-version=2018-06-01&versionType=branch&version=test_branch)

with a body

"properties": {
"annotations": [],
"type": "AzureKeyVault",
"typeProperties": {
"baseUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/"
}
Please is there a way to reference the branch and create this service in git mode

Comment: Have the same issue as you. I can create a new Linked Service to Azure Storage Gen2, against Synapse, using PowerShell, and also Terraform, yet the Linked Service on ly appears in Live Mode, but not Git Mode.

I have an open ticket with Microsoft Support on the matter. They were able to replicate my experience.

I used JSON file when creating using PowerShell, with `type = "AzureBlobFS"`

Answer (score 1):

As per official documentation, Changes made via PowerShell or an SDK are published directly to the Data Factory service, and are not entered into Git.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control